# How many custom events can I track with Fabric Answers?

Tags: fabric.io

I use Fabric.io custom events to track almost everything in my app, but it seems to max out at 20 events.

How many custom events can I track with Fabric Answers?

Comment: Hey, are you getting all the events now? I am facing the same issue as well.

Answer (score 4):

Mike from Fabric here.

You can track up to [3,000 specific events](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/answers/answers-events.html#answers-events) (custom or pre-defined with Answers).

Comment: I'm facing the same issue as well. It is limiting to the first few events of the day.

Comment: Only the top events will be shown within the dashboard, but you can search for any event or filter based on the values at the top.

Comment: Hi, Mike, I have tried that as well. For some reason, few events are not being logged. Can you please help me

Comment: Sounds like we will need to dig in more. I'd recommend contacting support(at)fabric(dot)io with the bundle id or package name of your app and the events logged that haven't been captured. Alternatively, try sending the events once more as we did have a production issue yesterday http://status.fabric.io/incidents/jdr09zfm8x9v